# Why isn't .equals recognizing my variable as the same string that I'm passing it?

Tags: java, equals, equivalence

So this little function is supposed to check if parentheses and brackets are matched next to each other. I feel like it should work and I've tried it a few different ways but I can't figure out how to check if my next char is what I expect it to be.

```
class Parenths {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        char[] parens = s.toCharArray();
        if (parens.length == 0) return true;
        for (int i = 0; i < parens.length; i+=2) {
            String curr= String.valueOf(parens[i]);
            String next = String.valueOf(parens[i+1]);
            // System.out.println(next.equals(")");      --------> false
            // System.out.println(Object.equals(next, ")")); ----> error
            switch (curr) {
                case "(": if (!next.equals(")")) return false;
                case "{": if (!next.equals("}")) return false;
                case "[": if (!next.equals("]")) return false;       
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can see the lines I printed to debug and it seems that .equals is not the right thing to use here? Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

PS. I realize I don't have to convert the string to a char array to compare elements, so unless that's the only fix, please don't point that out to me.

Comment: What is the error; and what is the value of `next`?

Comment: BTW: `parens[i] == ')'` would avoid the string conversion.

Comment: [edit] your question and post an example string that you pass as the method argument to `isValid()`

Comment: Please show the method from where you are calling the method isValid().

Comment: Here i resolved your problem in answer

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it seems to be a problem of fall through. <s>Try to replace `if (boolean) return boolean` with `return boolean`, this should do the trick.</s>

The problem is that you don't have a `break` at the end of the cases, so if, for example, your first case is true, it will not stop execution and execute the 2nd test, which will be false. If you change your conditional statements to a direct return, you will not have this problem.

EDIT: Sorry, I read too quickly. Doing so will break your loop. Actually, you have to add a `break` at the end of the cases.

```java
                case "(": if (!next.equals(")")) return false; break;
                case "{": if (!next.equals("}")) return false; break;
                case "[": if (!next.equals("]")) return false; break;
```

Comment: This will return `true` the instant that the first matching pair is found rather than check the whole string. You're correct about the fall through, but the solution is to add a `break` at the end of each case so that `false` is returned as soon as an invalid pair is found and `true` is returned by default

Answer (score 0):

First , you have to add `break;` after the cases its important to stop seeing the cases

```
 switch (curr) {
            case "(": if (!next.equals(")")) return false;
            break;
            case "{": if (!next.equals("}")) return false;
            break;
            case "[": if (!next.equals("]")) return false;   
            break;
        }
```

Secondly , your code doesnt support the confrotation of a closing patenthesis at first , you have to add a default case

```
           switch (curr) {
                case "(": if (!next.equals(")")) return false;
                break;
                case "{": if (!next.equals("}")) return false;
                break;
                case "[": if (!next.equals("]")) return false;    
                break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
            return true;
```

Also , you have to make sure the next element is not null before comparing to it , and dont increment with 2 , you give a String with a one element and that's why you get the error

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
        char[] parens = s.toCharArray();
        if (parens.length == 0) return true;
        for (int i = 0; i < parens.length; i++) {
            String curr= String.valueOf(parens[i]);
            String next = "";
            try { 
            next = String.valueOf(parens[i+1]); 

            switch (curr) {
                case "(": if (!next.equals(")")) return false;
                break;
                case "{": if (!next.equals("}")) return false;
                break;
                case "[": if (!next.equals("]")) return false;    
                break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        return false;
    }
```

---

- Test :

  ```
    System.out.println(isValid("()"));
    // Output : true
    System.out.println(isValid("("));
    // Output : false
  ```